# Bootstrap node modules problem with sticky-top

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4.3.1 in an Angular 7 project.

**angular.json**

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.scss"
],

"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
  "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
],
```

**style.scss**

```
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

Everything is working well, in fact I have been working for weeks and I have not had any problem, except for the `sticky-top` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/position/#sticky-top I do not understand why it does not work in my project.

I did a test on stackblitz and if it works https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ma79ds, then something is wrong with my project but I do not know what it can be.

```
<div class="col-4">
  <div class="sticky-top">
    My content...
  </div>  
</div>
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: You provided "what works" on your question but don't provide any code for your project that's not working. How are we suppose to help?

Comment: <div class="sticky-top">... it's the same thing that I tried in my code and it does not work

Comment: why use jquery in angular app? why not use [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/documentation#getting-started) that is bootstrap but for the ng apps